# Can a smart contract change the true value of ethereum in a wallet

Tags: etherscan

I have created an atomic wallet where stolen funds have been returned to me by a recovery company in ethereum.Ican see the eth in the wallet with a dollar value.An etherscan of the wallet address shows the eth to have no value.The recovery company claim the smart contract attached to these eth in the wallet is altering the true value of the eth.I have been advised by support @atomic that the funds are fake.However the recovery company say the smart contract is doing this.who do I believe?

Comment: If you check the wallet `0x8E8A9F07A1D54D9f25AC15DA8121DFAA6EA94A8E` it has 0.00119895 ethers as of 2023-08-01 at 2:36 UTC. The value is USD will change depending on the ETH market value. There's no contract attached to that address, so its ether balance won't change unless there's a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be totally sure but it seems that the recovery company is trying to scam you.

If in Etherscan the tokens have no value, it's possible the "recovery company" just created a worthless token and sent it to the wallet.

There's not really a concept of a smart contract "changing the true value of eth in a wallet". The true value comes from the market and from whether the token is the "correct" one. The dollar value of a token (or Ethereum) is not saved in a smart contract.

If you share the wallet address we might be able to know better. But right now it seems to me like a scam.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Kenzo.You may be right,I am being scammed.They are so convincing.Anyway I have also received advice from Blockchain Australia that they also think its a scam.They also warn me that if there is a smart contract attached to the funds i should be very cautious linking any wallets I have to the Atomic.Here is my ETH Address in the atomic. 0x8E8A9F07A1D54D9f25AC15DA8121DFAA6EA94A8E.   Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi did you get my reply   ???

Comment: Hi, yes. In short, it is a scam. The "Ethereum" that is written there is not the real Ethereum but a random token somebody made and called it "Ethereum". Not the real thing. Seeing as they are trying to convince you it is real, it is a scam.